make a variable to be assigned (initialized) only once
I have an infinite loop where in I'm receiving data from a network socket. The first 2 bytes of the received data define message identifier and I'm using memcpy to copy the bytes into an uint16_t. Is it possible to make the uint16_t msg_id variable to be assigned only once(memcpy). After this operation I shouldn't be allowed to assign a new value to uint16_t msg_id.
char buff[1024];
while (true) {
   const auto recvd_len = recvfrom(sock_fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, nullptr, nullptr);
   uint16_t msg_id;
   memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&msg_id), buff, sizeof(msg_id));
   // after the above operation msg_id should no longer be allowed to assign new value
   
   switch (msg_id) {
      case 0x0001: {
      }
      break;

      default:
      break;
   }
}


const uint16_t msg_id = *(uint16_t*)buff; is not legal C++ but it's a perfectly common style of coding and will do the same as your memcpy.

In your specific case, I would prefer the answer but in general, an immediately called lambda is my Swiss Army Knife for such situations: const Class obj = [&]{ Class obj; /* more statements here */ return obj; }();

@john what you're suggesting is undefined behavior. Don't do that.

easiest would be to initialize a const msg_id rather than using memcpy.  This would also allow you to "fix" the endianness rather than depending on the CPU endianness being the same as the 16 bit value:
const uint16_t msg_id = (buf[0] << 8) + (buf[1] & 0xff);  // fixed big-endian (network order) data, regardless of CPU byte ordering

Most compilers will optimize this as a single 16-bit move or a byteswap, depending on which is correct for your CPU.

Make it const. If initialization cannot be done together with declaration, wrap initialization in a function so you can initialize it on declaration:
const uint16_t msg_id = init_msg_id();

An immediately invoked lambda expression can come in handy:
const auto msg_id = [&](){
      uint16_t msg_id;
      memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&msg_id), buff, sizeof(msg_id));
      return msg_id;
}();

